# Warning: Internal React error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using bottomsheet modal to create a action sheet in my chat section in the react native app. And when i click the action it gives me error like this.

**ERROR**  Warning: Internal React error: Attempted to capture a commit phase error inside a detached tree. This indicates a bug in React. Likely causes include deleting the same fiber more than once, committing an already-finished tree, or an inconsistent return pointer.

**Error message:**

TypeError: undefined is not a function
in BottomSheet (created by BottomSheet)

this is my code and please help me to avoiding this error.

```js
import { BottomSheetModal } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context";
import Clipboard from "@react-native-community/clipboard";

import {
  Copy,
  CurveLineLeftUp,
  Delete,
  Edit,
  MessageFlag,
  Mute,
  Pin,
  Unpin,
  ThreadReply,
  pinned_by,
  Resend,
} from "stream-chat-react-native";

import { getChannelType } from "../../stream";

import { BottomSheetBackground } from "../../background/BottomSheetBackground";
import { ActionListContainer } from "./ActionListContainer";
import ChatClientService from "../../../utils/ChatClientService";
import { useMessageContext, useChannelContext } from "stream-chat-react-native";
const snapPoints = [300, 500];

export const MessageActionSheetSlack = React.forwardRef((props, fRef) => {
  const { activeMessage: message, activeChannel: channel } =
    useContext(AuthContext);
  const { actionHandlers, openReactionPicker: propMessageReactionPicker } =
    props;
  const chatClient = ChatClientService.getClient();

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const actionHandlersExist = !!actionHandlers;

  const openReactionPicker = () => {
    propMessageReactionPicker(message);
  };

  const openThread = () =>
    navigation.navigate("ThreadScreen", {
      channelId: channel.id,
      threadId: message.id,
    });
  const copyText = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(message.text);
  };

  const pin = async () => {
    await chatClient.pinMessage(message, null);
  };
  const unpin = async () => {
    await chatClient.unpinMessage(message);
  };

  const callHandlerAndDismissSheet = (handler, ...args) => {
    fRef.current?.dismiss();
    handler?.(...args);
  };

  const channelType = getChannelType(channel);

  const getTitle = (message) => {
    if (message) {
      if (
        channelType === "GROUP_CHANNEL" ||
        channelType === "INDIVIDUAL_CHANNEL"
      ) {
        if (message.pinned) {
          return "Unpin from this conversation";
        } else return "Pin to this conversation";
      } else {
        if (message.pinned) {
          return "Unpin from channel";
        } else return "Pin to channel";
      }
    }
  };
  const Title = getTitle(message);

  const options = () => {
    if (!actionHandlersExist) return [];

    const options = [];

    if (message) {
      if (message.user.id === chatClient.user.id) {
        options.push({
          Icon: Edit,
          handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(
            null,
            actionHandlers?.editMessage
          ),
          id: "edit",
          title: "Edit message",
        });
        options.push({
          Icon: Delete,
          handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(
            null,
            actionHandlers?.deleteMessage
          ),
          id: "delete",
          title: "Delete message",
        });
      }
      options.push({
        Icon: Copy,
        handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(null, copyText),
        id: "copy",
        title: "Copy text",
      });

      options.push({
        Icon: ThreadReply,
        handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(
          null,
          openThread,
          message.pinned == false
        ),
        id: "threadReply",
        title: "Reply in thread",
      });

      if (message.status != undefined && message.status === "failed") {
        options.push({
          id: "resend",
          title: "Resend message",
          icon: Resend,
          handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(
            null,
            actionHandlers?.resendMessage
          ),
        });
      } else {
        if (message.pinned == undefined || message.pinned === false) {
          options.push({
            Icon: message.pinned ? Pin : Unpin,
            handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(
              null,
              message.pinned ? unpin : pin
            ),
            id: "pin/unpin",
            title: Title,
          });
        } else {
          if (chatClient.user.id == message.pinned_by.id) {
            options.push({
              Icon: message.pinned ? Pin : Unpin,
              handler: callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(null, unpin),
              id: "pin/unpin",
              title: Title,
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return options;
  };

  const renderBackdrop = useCallback((props) => {
    const opacityStyle = useAnimatedStyle(
      () => ({
        opacity: (800 - props.animatedPosition.value) / 896,
      }),
      []
    );

    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
          {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
          opacityStyle,
        ]}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            fRef.current?.dismiss();
          }}
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject]}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }, []);

  if (!actionHandlersExist) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <BottomSheetModal
      backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
      backgroundComponent={BottomSheetBackground}
      ref={fRef}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
    >
      <ActionListContainer
        actions={options()}
        openReactionPicker={openReactionPicker}
        toggleReaction={callHandlerAndDismissSheet.bind(
          null,
          actionHandlers?.toggleReaction
        )}
      />
    </BottomSheetModal>
  );
});

MessageActionSheetSlack.displayName = "messageActionSheet";
```